# how to code commit on github using MINGW32?

Tags: github

i created a repositories on github.

now i want to put my some code there can anybody tell me how to do this and how to commit code.

i tried using this lines

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/Dany001/myrepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

please short out my problem

Thanks

Comment: and which error you'e get

Comment: permission denied(public key)                                       fatal:could not read from remote repository                      please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: have you added the public key into yuor github account?

Comment: how to add public key

Comment: generate key pair with `ssh-keygen` utility, and public part of the key (see it in .ssh/ folder, or in specified one by you) put into guthub on the proper page called "Account Settings/SSH Keys"

Comment: i have multiple keys in .ssh file how to identify exact key  to put there

Comment: you shell put to github public part, it usually have **.pub** extension like **id_dsa.pub**

Comment: i have put publickey in  my github account still is showing same error

Comment: There's no need to use a public key if pushing through https.

Comment: Has it been added into the key stack? Or, is it created by yours the repository, and yes then try to readd the origin as follows: `git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/Dany001/myrepo.git`,  the push changes. If the repository isn't yours, fork it. then add the proper origin, and push the changes.